# How to handle json file having new line characters in hive?

Tags: json, hive

I'm trying to load the json data into hive table. This json data contains newline characters. When I try to load this json data into hive table, it is not inserting properly.

## My hive table creation:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE serde_tab(
    gender STRING, name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/input/text' ;
```

## My json data:

```
{"gender":"femal\ne","name":"xyz"}
```

## My hive table data:

```
select * from serde_tab;
OK
serde_tab.gender    serde_tab.name
femal
e   xyz
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding the same ...

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me out ...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Dealing with the same problem in Athena, and there doesn't appear to be a way (short of importing the file as a different type, then shredding it via queries... and I'm not sure how usable that is)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **regexp_replace** function to replace **\n** with **''**.

```
hive> select regexp_replace(string("femal\ne"),'\n','');
+---------+--+
|   _c0   |
+---------+--+
| female  |
+---------+--+
```

**(or)**

Write a shell script to replace all \n newline characters with emptyvalues ('').

Comment: Actually, I'm not worried about the selection of particular column. I'm worried about the way the data is loading into hive table, one record is getting stored in two rows because of the newline character. Can we ignore newline character so that one record is stored in one row ?